# Pass field from other table on iteration

Tags: templates, go

I'm using golang, with sqlx and I'm trying to show on page the following output:

```
app_monitor.name    |  app_domains.name
```

Basically, it retrieves all monitor.name based on userid and get domain_name from other table. I can't manage to get the domain name from other table. Monitor name retrieval is successful. Should I get the domain_name in model, controller, or template engine?

Here is some fields in my database:

```
app_monitor: id, name, domain_id
user: id, domain_id
app_domains: id, name
```

My Model snippet:

```
type Monitor struct {
    ID          uint32        `db:"id"` // Don't use Id, use MonitorID() instead for consistency with MongoDB
    Name        string        `db:"name"`
    DID         uint32        `db:"domain_id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time     `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time     `db:"updated_at"`
    Status      uint8         `db:"status"`
    }
    func MonitorByUserID(userID string) ([]Monitor, error) {
    var err error

    var result []Monitor

    switch database.ReadConfig().Type {
    case database.TypeMySQL:
        err = database.SQL.Select(&result, "SELECT app_monitor.id, app_monitor.name, app_monitor.status FROM app_monitor LEFT JOIN user ON app_monitor.domain_id = user.domain_id WHERE user.id = ?", userID)
    default:
        err = ErrCode
    }

    return result, standardizeError(err)
}
```

My Controller

```
func MonitorReadGET(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Get session
    sess := session.Instance(r)

    userID := fmt.Sprintf("%s", sess.Values["id"])

    monitors, err := model.MonitorByUserID(userID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        monitors = []model.Monitor{}
    }

    // Display the view
    v := view.New(r)
    v.Name = "monitor/read"
    v.Vars["first_name"] = sess.Values["first_name"]
    v.Vars["monitors"] = monitors
    v.Render(w)
}
```

And finally My Template

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col-9">Monitor</th>
        <th scope="col-3">Action</th>
    </tr>
        {{range $n := .monitors}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.Name.DomainName}}</td>
        <td><a title="Edit Monitor" class="btn btn-warning" role="button" href="{{$.BaseURI}}monitor/update/{{.MonitorID}}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
            </a>
            <a title="Delete Monitor" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" href="{{$.BaseURI}}monitor/delete/{{.MonitorID}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        {{end}}
</table>
```

But it says

```
Template File Error: template: read.tmpl:27:47: executing "content" at <.Name.DomainName>: can't evaluate field DomainName in type string
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem in the template is:

```
<td>{{.Name.DomainName}}</td>
```

Name is defined as a `string` field on the `Monitor` type. Being a string, it does not have a sub-field named `DomainName`. Hence the error:

> can't evaluate field DomainName in type string

Additionally, the
`database.SQL.Select(&result, "SELECT app_monitor.id, app_monitor.name, app_monitor.status FROM app_monitor LEFT JOIN user ON app_monitor.domain_id = user.domain_id WHERE user.id = ?", userID)`
statement in the model package is not retrieving the DomainName. You'll want to select the other model fields that need to be rendered too.
Once the SQL is updated appropriately the following snippet should render the desired output:

```
<td>{{.Name}}</td>
<td>{{.DomainName}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Stevie, you gave a useful hint. Finally, I can make it works.